# Group mutliple array values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

What I need is to take an issue id and track user submitted upvotes by the hour. I'm running into a wall when I try to get the data out of the array coherently for PHPExcel charting purposes.

I end up with this $hourlyUpvotesTodayResult[] array, which has the correct number of votes for each hour (verified through print_r), but I want to group them in such a way where I can do something like "for each issue id display the hours 0-24 and the total votes for each hour". Maybe I'm overthinking it and missing something simple.

Also, please ignore the ancient MySQL - I'm working on some existing code, I know it's deprecated and I'll get around to updating it someday :D

```
while ($todayInfoRow = mysql_fetch_array($todayInfoQuery))
    {
    $issue_entry_id_today = array($todayInfoRow['issue_entry_id']);
    foreach ($issue_entry_id_today as $issue_entry_id_today)
        {
        $todayInfoUpvotes = "SELECT id from $db.$tb2 WHERE date = '".$date."' and issue_entry_id = '".$issue_entry_id_today."' ORDER BY issue_entry_id DESC";
        $todayInfoUpvotesQuery = mysql_query($todayInfoUpvotes)or die(mysql_error());
        $todayInfoUpvotesRow = mysql_num_rows($todayInfoUpvotesQuery);
        $todayInfoResult = array($issue_entry_id_today, $todayInfoUpvotesRow);
        }
    // get votes for individual hours for today 
    for ($hour_today=0; $hour_today<25; $hour_today++)
        {
            $hourlyUpvotesToday = "SELECT id from $db.$tb2 WHERE date = '".mysql_real_escape_string($date)."' AND issue_entry_id = '".$issue_entry_id_today."' AND hour = '".$hour_today."' ORDER BY issue_entry_id DESC";
            $hourlyUpvotesTodayQuery = mysql_query($hourlyUpvotesToday)or die(mysql_error());
            $hourlyUpvotesTodayRow = mysql_num_rows($hourlyUpvotesTodayQuery);
            $hourlyUpvotesTodayResult[] = array('id'=>$issue_entry_id_today, 'upvotes'=>$hourlyUpvotesTodayRow, 'hour'=>$hour);
        } 
    }
//debug print array
print_r($hourlyUpvotesTodayResult);
```

Comment: could you do me a favor and post the print_r for a better visual?

Comment: It's pretty lengthy, let me cut it down a bit.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 30 [upvotes] => 0 [hour] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 30 [upvotes] => 0 [hour] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 30 [upvotes] => 0 [hour] => 2 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 30 [upvotes] => 0 [hour] => 3 ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 30 [upvotes] => 0 [hour] => 4 ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 30 [upvotes] => 0 [hour] => 5 ) [6] => Array ( [id] => 30 [upvotes] => 0 [hour] => 6 ) [7] => Array ( [id] => 30 [upvotes] => 0 [hour] => 7 ) etc, on and on for each issue and each hour per issue

Comment: Oh i meant like editing the post and formatting it like the code lol sorry shoulda been more specific.

Comment: Done! Post has been edited.

Comment: So what I'm getting is that you want to represent a trend in this data and show the cumulative build-up, by the hour, of how many upvotes are given, for one day.  Either that or you want each individual hour and not a total of the ones before it.  Close?

Comment: Individual hour. The end goal is to present this in Excel format - in pseudocode what I need is "for each issue, display the number of votes for each hour by the hour"

Comment: I don't want to post this an answer because it might totally not be what you're looking for... But, can I suggest taking `$todayInfoResult = array($issue_entry_id_today, $todayInfoUpvotesRow);` and changing it to `$todayInfoResult[] = array($issue_entry_id_today => $todayInfoUpvotesRow);` instead? I'd be curious to know if that gets you closer to your goal.

Comment: I've the today part figured out, just stuck on the hourly since there are so many values. The today queries are inconsequential. I think I see what you did with making the key the id though...let me think on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code creates the array with a little extra info.  Instead of making an array of:

> Hour number
>
> > ID #
> >
> > > hour
> > >
> > > > votes

You'll make one that results in:

> ID #
>
> > [Hour] -> Votes

This time, ID # will be the key, your Hour will be the X value and your Votes will be the Y value (referencing a basic X-Y axis chart).  Your array will change to this:

```
$hourlyUpvotesTodayResult[$issue_entry_id_today] = array($hour => $hourlyUpvotesTodayRow);
```

You'll have to put the for statement entirely inside the above foreach statement.  Then you can print each one by its issue number like you need.

Not sure about PHPExcel but you can post this by doing essentially the same foreach { for {} } group-loop, just this time without the SQL calls since it's already in the array.

Outside of the for() loop you would put something like:

```
print "ID number for this issue: " . $issue_entry_id_today . "<br>";
```

Inside that loop you'd have:

```
print "Hour " . $hour . " produced " . $hourlyUpvotesTodayResult[$issue_entry_id_today][$hour] . " votes.";
```

And you could put that into a table or div's or whatever you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad I could help. Enjoy :)